# Python - Update an old_list if a new_list has a different value

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to make a script where I check a old_list and a new_list. If the new_list has a different values than Old_list. It will check with a if-elif statement if the old_list has more values/element than new_list and if it has it shouldn't do anything and vice versa.

```
old_list = {'name': 'Hello', 'code': ['Medium', 'Easy', 'Hard']}

while True:

    new_list = {'name': 'Stackoverflow', 'code': ['Hard', 'Easy']}

    try:
        if any(i not in old_list['code'] for i in new_list['code']):

            if old_list['code'] > new_list['code']:
                print("Element removed")
                old_list['code'] = new_list['code']

            elif old_list['code'] < new_list['code']:
                print("New elements added")
                old_list['code'] = new_list['code']

        else:
            randomtime = random.randint(1, 2)
            time.sleep(randomtime)
            continue

    except Exception as err:
        randomtime = random.randint(1, 2)
        time.sleep(randomtime)
        continue
```

The output should be **"Element removed"** and the value should update `old_list['code']` from `['Medium', 'Easy', 'Hard']`to `['Hard', 'Easy']`. But right now it doesn't even go through the `if any(i not in old_list['code'] for i in new_list['code']):` since the values in `code` are in both but there is no "Medium" in new_list but for some reason which I don't know it doesn't get through and it does the `else` instead.

How can I possible make it so it updates the values if new_list has more/less values/elements than old_list and then print out if element gets removed or added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if any(i not in old_list['code'] for i in new_list['code']):`

This condition will be satisfied only if any element of `new_list['code']` is not in `old_list['code']`. your `new_list` is `['Hard','Easy']`. Both are present in `old_list`, thus condition is not satisfied and your code goes to the `else` part.

If all you want to do is find out elements removed or elements added,
you can just check lenghts of new_list and old_list.

```
if len(old_list['code']) > len(new_list['code']):
    print("Elements removed")
    old_list['code'] = new_list['code']
elif len(old_list['code']) < len(new_list['code']):
    print("New elements added")
    old_list['code'] = new_list['code']
else:
    temp = set(old_list['code']).intersection(set(new_list['code']))
    if len(temp) == len(old_list['code']):
        pass # No change
    else
        print "Elements Removed and Added"
        old_list['code'] = new_list['code']
```

Comment: Oh thats actually true now when you explained it. Meaning I don't really even needed a if loop at the beginning in first place? What about if element old list contains Hard Easy and New list contains Medium Beginner - the length is still gonna be 2 vs 2 but the contain is not the same?

Comment: well then it depends what you want as the output for [hard, easy] and [Medium, Beginner]. elements added or elements removed or both?

Comment: Only when it is added/totally changed is the output I want. But whenever it hits the 'element removed' it should just update the old_list. In our case it should change [hard, easy] to [medium, beginner].

Comment: okay...take intersection of old and new list if the lengths are same. if the intersection result length is same as old/new list length, there is no change. Otherwise there was removal and addition

Comment: Oh alright! I dont know what intersection does. Never heard about it. I will try give this a go!

Comment: It's like finding out common elements in two lists. intersection of [Hard, Easy] and [Medium, Easy] will be [Easy] See my answer for how to use it.

Comment: Oh alright! so I assume where you entered the "pass" is where I do a sleep whenever there is no changes if I am correct? Because otherwise this would just spam endless?

Comment: I think this might be the answer I was looking for! Im still trying to understand what intersection really does but I will do some google searches for it instead. I will give this a shot and try to do step by step but it seems to be my solution however! - It is just the Else statement that I doesn't really grip. What does that really do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184978/discussion-between-greenlantern-and-hellosiroverthere).